# How to list only regular files (excluding directories) under a directory in Python

Tags: python, filesystems

One can use `os.listdir('somedir')` to get all the files under `somedir`. However, if what I want is just regular files (excluding directories) like the result of `find . -type f` under shell.

I know one can use `[path for path in os.listdir('somedir') if not os.path.isdir('somedir/'+path)]` to achieve similar result as in this related question: [How to list only top level directories in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141291/how-to-list-only-top-level-directories-in-python). Just wondering if there are more succinct ways to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), which returns a tuple of path, folders and files:

```
files = next(os.walk('somedir'))[2]
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a couple of ways that i do such tasks. I cannot comment on the succinct nature of the solution. FWIW here they are:

1.the code below will take all files that end with .txt. you may want to remove the ".endswith" part

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'): #current directory in terminal
     for file in files:
             if file.endswith('.txt'):
             #here you can do whatever you want to with the file.
```

2.This code here will assume that the path is provided to the function and will append all .txt files to a list and if there are subdirectories in the path, it will append those files in the subdirectories to subfiles

```
def readFilesNameList(self, path):
    basePath = path
    allfiles = []
    subfiles = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basePath):
      for f in files:
         if f.endswith('.txt'):
             allfiles.append(os.path.join(root,f))
             if root!=basePath:
                 subfiles.append(os.path.join(root, f))
```

I know the code is just skeletal in nature but i think you can get the general picture.
post if you find the succinct way! :)

Answer (score 0):

The earlier `os.walk` answer is perfect if you only want the files in the top-level directory.  If you want subdirectories' files too, though (a la `find`), you need to process each directory, e.g.:

```
def find_files(path):
    for prefix, _, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            yield os.path.join(prefix, name)
```

Now `list(find_files('.'))` is a list of the same thing `find . -type f -print` would have given you (the `list` is because find_files is a generator, in case that's not obvious).