# Use os.listdir to show directories only

Tags: python, raw-input, os.path

How can I bring python to only output directories via `os.listdir`, while specifying which directory to list via `raw_input`?

What I have:

```
file_to_search = raw_input("which file to search?\n>")

dirlist=[]

for filename in os.listdir(file_to_search):
    if os.path.isdir(filename) == True:
        dirlist.append(filename)

print dirlist
```

Now this actually works if I input (via `raw_input`) the current working directory. However, if I put in anything else, the list returns empty. I tried to divide and conquer this problem but individually every code piece works as intended.

Comment: Could you share what you entered in the `raw_input` field and what OS you use?

Comment: Just for the record since Jean-Francois solution worked:
examples of what I entered: C:/, D:/X/Y, C:\, D:\X\Y, D:\\X\\Y
OS: Windows

Answer (score 19, accepted):

that's expected, since `os.listdir` only returns the *names* of the files/dirs, so objects are not found, unless you're running it in the current directory.

You have to `join` to scanned directory to compute the full path for it to work:

```
for filename in os.listdir(file_to_search):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(file_to_search,filename)):
        dirlist.append(filename)
```

note the list comprehension version:

```
dirlist = [filename for filename in os.listdir(file_to_search) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(file_to_search,filename))]
```

Comment: Better use walk here see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63715910/281545 `dirlist = [d for d in next(os.walk(file_ro_search))[1]]`